# How can I Give Print command from iPhone to printer via bluetooth?

Tags: iphone

I want to implement such app from which without any external connectivity, I want to print img,text,pdf from my iPhone device to printer. I want to use only bluetooth connection between device and printer. I go through few related questions to this one, but not able to get sure suggestions. Some are telling go by External Accessory, some are telling to go by GameKit. What to do exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't use GameKit for this: GameKit is only to talk to other iOS devices.

Are you the manufacturer of the printer? If so, you could use External Accessory via the Made for iPhone program, but you'll have to contact Apple to find out what that entails (as the details are not public knowledge).

If you are not the printer manufacturer, then your only option is if the printer supports Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy mode. If it does, your app can talk to it using the [Core Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html) framework.

If you're not the printer manufacturer, and the printer doesn't support Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Further to this, you might not actually have to enroll in MFI but merely find out the printer protocol from the manufacturer.